# Homotopy fibers and preimages of regular values.

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $f \colon M \to N$ be a smooth map between two manifolds. Let $q_0 \in N$ be a regular value of $f$. Is there a relation between the homotopy fiber of $f$ and the submanifold $f^{-1}(q_0)$?

Comment: Not if $f$ is just an arbitrary map, I don't think. The different point-preimages of $f$ can be very different, but the homotopy fibre of a map is determined up to homotopy equivalence. However if $f$ is surjective, a submersion (ALL points are regular) and proper, then Ehresmann's fibration theorem says it's a locally trivial fibration, and so the homotopy and point-fibres are homotopy equivalent.

Comment: If you know some Morse Theory it's a good example of when point pre-images do and don't change. Given a Morse function $f\colon M \to \mathbb{R}$, if $I = [a, b]$ is a closed interval of regular values in $\mathbb{R}$ then $f^{-1}I$ is diffeomorphic to a cylinder $f^{-1}(a) \times I$. However if $[a, b]$ contains a unique non-degenerate critical point $c$, then the diffeomorphism types of $f^{-1}(a)$ and $f^{-1}(b)$ differ by a handle whose index is the Morse index of c.